# three.js orbitControl disables writing in textboxes in Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, three.js

for some reason my three.js application disabled me from writing anything in my text field  or even clicking it in my Ruby on rails application.
does anyone know why that might be the case?
my three jsapplication looks like this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('player');
if(box){
var boxSize = box.clientWidth;
}
var $player;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var camera, scene, renderer;
var mixer, skeletonHelper;

init();
animate();
loadBVH('<%= asset_path 'forehand.bvh' %>');

function init() {

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 100, 400 );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.enableZoom = false;

controls.minDistance = 300;
controls.maxDistance = 700;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 200, 10 ) );
// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xeeeeee );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( boxSize, boxSize );

$player = $('#player');
$player.append(renderer.domElement);

}

function loadBVH (pathBVH) {
var loader = new THREE.BVHLoader();
loader.load(pathBVH, function( result ) {

    skeletonHelper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( result.skeleton.bones[ 0 ] );
    skeletonHelper.skeleton = result.skeleton;

    var boneContainer = new THREE.Group();
    boneContainer.add( result.skeleton.bones[ 0 ] );

    scene.add( skeletonHelper );
    scene.add( boneContainer );


    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( skeletonHelper );
    mixer.clipAction( result.clip ).setEffectiveWeight( 1.0 ).play();

});
}

function animate(){

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

var delta = clock.getDelta();

if ( mixer ) mixer.update( delta );
if ( skeletonHelper ) skeletonHelper.update();

renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


function showMotion(role, mood, param, name, weight, gender, body_height, shoulder_width,
shoulder_height, inner_leg_length, tibia_length, body_depth, hip_width, seat_height,
shoulder_elbow_length, elbow_wrist_length, chest_girth, waist_girth, thigh_girth, path){

var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById("details");
fieldNameElement.innerHTML =
    '<h4 class="motion-font">' + 'Motion: '
    + '</h4>'
    + '<div class="motion-font">'
    + 'Role: ' + role + '<br/>'
    + 'Mood: ' +  mood + '<br/>'
    + 'Description: ' + param + '<br/>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<h4 class="motion-font">' + 'Actor: '
    + '</h4>'
    + '<div class="motion-font">'
    + 'name: ' +  name + '<br/>'
    + 'weight: ' +  weight + '<br/>'
    + 'gender: ' +  gender + '<br/>'
    + 'body height: ' +  body_height + '<br/>'
    + 'shoulder width: ' +  shoulder_width + '<br/>'
    + 'shoulder height: ' +  shoulder_height + '<br/>'
    + 'inner leg length: ' +  inner_leg_length + '<br/>'
    + 'tibia length: ' + tibia_length  + '<br/>'
    + 'body depth: ' + body_depth  + '<br/>'
    + 'hip width: ' +  hip_width + '<br/>'
    + 'seat height: ' + seat_height  + '<br/>'
    + 'shoulder elbow length: ' +  shoulder_elbow_length + '<br/>'
    + 'elbow wrist length: ' +  elbow_wrist_length + '<br/>'
    + 'chest girth: ' +  chest_girth + '<br/>'
    + 'waist girth: ' +  waist_girth + '<br/>'
    + 'thigh girth: ' + thigh_girth  + '<br/>'
    + '</div>';

scene.remove( skeletonHelper );
clock = new THREE.Clock();
loadBVH(path);

}
```

After some testing i figured out that it is the line

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
```

that creates the Problems. But i dont really know what exactly it could do to give me problems like that.
Also, my text box looks like this:

```
<%= select_tag :search_mood, options_from_collection_for_select(Motion.all.uniq{ |x| x.mood }, :mood, :mood, params[:search_mood]), include_blank:  true, class: 'js-example-placeholder-single mood' %>
```

Comment: How do you mean *disables your from writing anything in your text field*? Your issue is very vague. Maybe your canvas element is simply in front of your text input element? Maybe you should check your element tree?

Comment: @Wilt it just disables me from even clicking on the textfield. i can't interact with it at all. I took the script out and then it worked. About the element tree, sry, i have not idea what that is

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I should have calle the Three.OrbitControl like this:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```